# How to estimate the probability of more failures after the system running a certain amount of time?

Tags: survival, recurrent-events

We have a system that takes some input and process the input. It often takes more than 10 hours to finish processing. If it takes more than 24 hours, the processing often gets cancelled. During the whole process, failures (either due to the system itself or the input) may occur, and requires human to fix them and resume the processing. After that, more failures can still occur before the whole process is done or cancelled.

We have historical data on when all failures occur, and when each process is done or cancelled. How do I estimate the probability of more failures after the system has been running a certain amount of time?

My naive approach is to take the time of last failure in each run (if there is no failure, then the time is 0), and calculate the survival function for the last failure time.

However, this approach ignores the possibility that, if a specific run failed more times before a certain time, it might be more likely to fail even more after that time (Matthew effect). How do I test the existence of Matthew effect? If Matthew effect does exist, how do I estimate the survival/hazard function? How do I perform such analysis in R?

Comment: The relationship between failures and cancellations is unclear - also, you would need to consider the distribution of repair time.

Comment: I also have historical data on the repair time. Failures can delay the whole process, delaying increases the chance of it being cancelled. But there is not strict rule on what gets cancelled.

Comment: I have not used it myself, but perhaps the `survrec` package can help you in fitting a model with recurring events.